# Session management with parameter tagging / p:button /p:commandButton

Tags: java, session, primefaces, xhtml

I have a web application which have to implement login. user provide username and pwd after authenticating user should redirect to page which they have privilages pages are differant from user to user. Sometimes 2 or more users can get same page but available data should differant for do this I have pass users privilage ID(divisionId) to other beans

for now i have tried URL tagging parameter tagged to URL and dirrect to page successfully but I can't take it to bean variable.

Itried this with p:Button then textbox inputs won't get to bean class to execute the method when button click.

xhtml code -

```
 <h:body>

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" visible="true" closable="false" >        
        <h:form id="form">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: " />  
                <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" 
                             required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Username"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />  
                <p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                            required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Password"/>                 
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton id="LoggingButton" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin()}"
                                 update=":growl" oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args),">

                </p:commandButton>

        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

loginbean-

```
public class LoginBean{


private String username;
private String password;
private int divisionId;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of loginBean
 */

public LoginBean() {
}

public String doLogin() {


    DbUser du = new DbUser();
    divisionId = du.ValidateUser(username, password);


    if(divisionId==0)
        addMessage("Invalied username or password", false);
    else{

        if(divisionId==1){ 

//              return "superuser.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
            return "superuser.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true";
            //superAdmin                         
       }
        else if(divisionId==2||divisionId==3){

//               return "engadmin_create_div.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
           return "engadmin_create_div.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true";
            //ENG/IT ADMIN

        }
        else{
//                return "viewonly_user.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
            return "viewonly_user.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true";
            //View only users
        }
    }
     return null;        
}
```

Comment: Your issue is: textbox can not get to bean ?

Comment: I get textbox values to bean when using commandButton. When I use Button it won't happen.

Comment: You use button to pass parameter to other page ?

Comment: You can use commandbutton and try:
        ExternalContext ext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ext.redirect(ext.getRequestContextPath() + "superuser.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true");
     to redirect to target you want.

Comment: redirecting happen successfully but i can't get divisionId to parameter to new loading page bean class passing should happen after login button click. login button is a commandButton eg- I need to pass divisionId from loginBean to adminBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that work :)

```
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" visible="true" closable="false" >        
        <h:form id="form">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: " />  
                <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" 
                             required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Username"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />  
                <p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                            required="true" requiredMessage="Enter Password"/>                 
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton id="LoggingButton" value="Login" actionListener="#{loginBean.doLogin()}">

                </p:commandButton>

        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

Bean

```
public class LoginBean{


private String username;
private String password;
private int divisionId;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of loginBean
 */

public LoginBean() {
}
public static void redirect(String strDes) throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ext.redirect(ext.getRequestContextPath() + strDes);
}
public void doLogin() {


    DbUser du = new DbUser();
    divisionId = du.ValidateUser(username, password);


    if(divisionId==0)
        addMessage("Invalied username or password", false);
    else{

        if(divisionId==1){ 
            LoginBean.redirect("superuser.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true");
            //superAdmin                         
       }
        else if(divisionId==2||divisionId==3){    
           LoginBean.redirect("engadmin_create_div.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true");
            //ENG/IT ADMIN    
        }
        else{
            LoginBean.redirect("viewonly_user.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true");
            //View only users
        }
    }       
}
```

you get parameter from bean:

```
Map<String,String> params = 
                FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
      String action = params.get("test");
```

Comment: where should i need to call this method

Comment: In the target page you redirect to :)

Comment: what is the input for strDes

Comment: The target you want in doLogin(); ex: "superuser.xhtml?test="+divisionId+"faces-redirect=true";